# How to avoid "Out of Memory" crash during an image resizing function?

Tags: swift, memory

I am using the [SDWebImageHEIFCoder](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageHEIFCoder/issues) library to support HEIC files on older iOS < 11. The app relies on images provided by end-users and converts them to JPG using this library. However, my question is general to any "image processing" function which would be a heavy memory consumer.

Particularly, the issue is that I have no control over the images from end-users. Sometimes, if the HEIC image is too big, the app runs into an 'Out of Memory' error and crashes.

Is there anyway to handle that better?
Example:

- Stop the resizing function execution in case the app detects a high memory usage.
- Estimate in advance if a particular image (based on size and devices specs) would result in an 'out of memory' issue to avoid trying to convert it.
- etc.

Here is my code using the external library:

```
func resizePicture() -> UIImage? {
// Define MaxResolution based on screen resolution and scale
let maxResolution = Int( Float(Swift.max(UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.height)) * Float(UIScreen.main.scale) )

// HEIF Decoder (iOS < 11)
if #available(iOS 11.0, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.0, *) {
    // These version supports Image/IO built-in decoding --> Continue with standard code below
} else {
    print("♻️ HEIF Decoding using SDWebImageHEIFCoder")
    let HEIFCoder = SDImageHEIFCoder.shared
    SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(HEIFCoder)
    
    if let heifData = try? Data(contentsOf: self.localURL) {
        let thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: maxResolution, height: maxResolution)
        let image = SDImageHEIFCoder.shared.decodedImage(with: heifData, options: [.decodeThumbnailPixelSize: thumbnailSize])
        return image
    }
}
```

...

Comment: While it won't directly address your question, consider adding the options `[.mappedIfSafe, .uncached]` to your `Data(contentsOf:)` to possibly improve your problem. If this file is very large, you don't want it to evict everything else from the filesystem caches. And mapping the file may significantly reduce your memory usage (I haven't checked if `.mappedIfSafe` is the current default in iOS, which is why I'm not certain if it will help. Always profile in Instruments to be more certain.) Also, can you confirm that you're crash is on a single resize, and this isn't in a loop?

Comment: Thank you @RobNapier for your help! I am not running into a loop, the image is only treated once. I tried adding these two new options without any improvements. I am supporting old devices and the app crashes when it uses 130Mb on an old iPad mini (approx 1/4 of total available). I know that supporting old devices still running iOS 9.3.5 is very challenging so my question was more of a generic one on how to deal with such situations ;-) Thank you for having taken some time to answer.

Comment: Are you receiving a `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` message before you're killed? Given how this is working, it may be hard to make use of that, but it's worth at least checking. Also of dubious help: I have had experience, especially on older iOS versions, with the OS killing the app not because it actually ran out of memory but because it requested memory too quickly. My suggestion is to do a lot of profiling to see precisely where the memory is being allocated and particularly look for any unnecessary copies.

Comment: Also, if possible, you may be able to pre-allocate a buffer backed by NSPurgeableData. My memory of that type is that it doesn't count directly towards your use. (Of course if you actually run out of memory, it could be discarded; and it may still count against you while you're in a contentAccess block, which is probably when you need it... but still, something to explore.) I would also dig through libheif itself to see if you can improve memory usage (and possibly bypass SDWebImageHEIFCoder and import libheif directly to Swift to avoid some ObjC bridging).

Comment: But #1 is going to be profiling profiling profiling. Figure out exactly when the memory is allocated and how much, relative to the input data. If you're crashing at the `Data(contentsOf:)` call, that's very different than if you're crashing at some point deep inside of libheif, or somewhere in the middle in SDImageHEIFCoder. Best of luck. This is a very interesting challenge.